# Start the function again in Python when code ends

Tags: python

i  create little code

```
def Basket(): #the  start of the code

    items1=[]

    items1=input("type items\n")

    options=int(input("choose options\n"))

    if options==1:
        print("items on basket are:\n", items1)

    elif options==2:
        print(items1.count(',')+1) #the end

Basket()
```

i  want to use the program  again  and  again with out to close it
so i need  that  the  program alwase go to the  start of the code after  the  end
help ?

Comment: `while True: Basket()`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
def Basket(): #the  start of the code

    while True:
        items1=[]

        items1=input("type items\n")

        options=int(input("choose options\n"))

        if options==1:
            print("items on basket are:\n", items1)

        elif options==2:
            print(items1.count(',')+1) #the end

Basket()
```

OR (as @zvone commented)

```
def Basket(): #the  start of the code

    items1=[]

    items1=input("type items\n")

    options=int(input("choose options\n"))

    if options==1:
        print("items on basket are:\n", items1)

    elif options==2:
        print(items1.count(',')+1) #the end

while True: Basket()
```

OR (Elegantly)

```
def Basket(): #the  start of the code

    while input("add an item ? (y:Yes or n:No) \n") == "y":
        items1=[]

        items1=input("type items\n")

        options=int(input("choose options\n"))

        if options==1:
            print("items on basket are:\n", items1)

        elif options==2:
            print(items1.count(',')+1) #the end

Basket()
```